# Putting Flask and Phonegap together

Tags: flask, phonegap-desktop-app

I have this app built with flask and now i'm trying to run it on my phone with phonegap.
Although the way i have it organized originally with flask is something like this:

```
/project
    run-dev.py
    config.py
    /phonegapfolder
    /app
        user.py
        forms.py
        views.py
        __init__.py
        /templates
            index.html
```

My problem comes from the fact that phonegap demands its main html to be the one in

```
/phonegapfolder/www/index.html
```

Of course it's useless to just copy my index.html from one folder from another, because we will not find the python files that lie within the app folder.

Answer (score 1):

You best solution would be to use flask on a backend (remote) server and have the PhoneGap application make server requests to the flask server.

PhoneGap projects require that the index.html be set within the application (www) folder.

This [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3u39gb/can_apache_cordova_python_and_flask_be_used_to/) on Reddit might be able to clarify some of the details.